# How to do Moving average in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I am plotting a hysteresis graph in matlab of Pressure vs Resistance and i want to smooth the graph so i want the moving average of these two variable series. Can anybody help me with that situation. Both variable contains 170 values each.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? There is plenty out there on how to do this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matlab's `smooth` function gives various ways of smoothing your data. The default is a moving average with a span of 5, but you can play around with this span or indeed try different smoothing techniques.

For example:

```
smooth(y) % Moving average with a window of 5
smooth(y, 3) % Moving average with a window of 3
smooth(y, 'sgolay', 3) % Savitz-Golay filter
```

Reference can be found [here](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/smooth.html).

I believe it is part of the curve fitting toolbox though...